# Multiple flip instances (images)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, transform

I was wondering on how to achieve this. For instance, I have four versions of a logo and I want to go through all of them through a flip effect. Example:

Logo 1 (waits a couple of seconds) > flips to Logo 2 (waits a couple of seconds) > flips to Logo 3 (waits a couple of seconds) > flips to Logo 4. All these with a perspective animation.

Just like you would flip a coin but you flip 4 instances of the logo.

I don't really know how to make the flipping animation go automatically. I found some stuff but they flip on hover or click + you can flip 2 instances (front and back).

Perhaps you can point me to some relevant tutorials or something like that.

Thank you.

Comment: [**This**](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) should get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally possible with CSS3 only!

Instead of using transition (witch is triggered by an action from the user), use css animations. There is a great video introducing folks to CSS animations over on CSS-tricks.com and I recommend you [check it out](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/97-intro-to-css-animations/) to see how get your head around it and how to make it work on many browsers but, in a nutshell, you start by declaring the animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes nameTheAnimation { /* what will it do */ }
```

And then you go over the element that you want to animate and add the animation:

```
-webkit-animation: nameTheAnimation 'delay in s' 'time in s';
```

For details on what properties are available, you can [check w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)